# What is an efficient way to replace list of strings with another list in Unix file?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, file-io

Suppose I have two lists of strings (list A and list B) with the exact same number of entries, N, in each list, and I want to replace all occurrences of the the nth element of A with the nth element of B in a file in Unix (ideally using Bash scripting).

What's the most efficient way to do this?

An inefficient way would be to make N calls to "`sed s/stringA/stringB/g`".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will do it in one pass. It reads listA and listB into awk arrays, then for each line of the linput, it examines each word and if the word is found in listA, the word is replaced by the corresponding word in listB.

```
awk '
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] { listA[$1] = FNR; next }
    FILENAME == ARGV[2] { listB[FNR] = $1; next }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            if ($i in listA) {
                $i = listB[listA[$i]]
            }
        }
        print
    }
' listA listB filename > filename.new
mv filename.new filename
```

I'm assuming the strings in listA do not contain whitespace (awk's default field separator)

Comment: Nice, overall, but with a potential problem. This solution does not necessarily preserve the interword spacing on lines where changes get made; runs of whitespace get changed to single spaces. Since we don't know the nature of the text, it might not be a problem and may even turn out to be an advantage. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: This is clearly more efficient than the solution below that writes a sed script. Finished in 3 minutes what took 3 days using the sed solution. Also replaces only whole words, even though this is not what was asked.

Comment: This solves the purpose, but how to preserve the white spaces? It appears the awk script replaces them with just one whitespace.

Comment: You would use the `substr` function to find the section of the line before and after the word you want to substitute, and concatenate those pieces with the replacement. Or rewrite in perl where it's easier to maintain the separators

Answer (score 7):

Make one call to `sed` that writes the sed script, and another to use it?  If your lists are in files `listA` and `listB`, then:

```
paste -d : listA listB | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)/s%\1%\2%/' > sed.script
sed -f sed.script files.to.be.mapped.*
```

I'm making some sweeping assumptions about 'words' not containing either colon or percent symbols, but you can adapt around that.  Some versions of `sed` have upper bounds on the number of commands that can be specified; if that's a problem because your word lists are big enough, then you may have to split the generated sed script into separate files which are applied - or change to use something without the limit (Perl, for example).

Another item to be aware of is sequence of changes.  If you want to swap two words, you need to craft your word lists carefully.  In general, if you map (1) wordA to wordB and (2) wordB to wordC, it matters whether the sed script does mapping (1) before or after mapping (2).

The script shown is not careful about word boundaries; you can make it careful about them in various ways, depending on the version of `sed` you are using and your criteria for what constitutes a word.

Comment: There's also the potential problem of one word in B being totally or partially in A. A true solution would probably require breaking the input into words and changing them once if at all.

Comment: @lhf: I think the problem you mention is covered by my discussion about word boundaries.  The correct behaviour, in any case, depends on the problem definition.  Changing a word at most once is a plausible definition, but is not the only one.  You can even code for that with `sed`, using the '`t`' command after each substitute operation.

Comment: If you have '\' in the replacement string they get stripped out so need to be replaced with '\\' in the script, but otherwise this is an awesome solution!

Answer (score 6):

I needed to do something similar, and I wound up generating sed commands based on a map file:

```
$ cat file.map
abc => 123
def => 456
ghi => 789

$ cat stuff.txt
abc jdy kdt
kdb def gbk
qng pbf ghi
non non non
try one abc

$ sed `cat file.map | awk '{print "-e s/"$1"/"$3"/"}'`<<<"`cat stuff.txt`"
123 jdy kdt
kdb 456 gbk
qng pbf 789
non non non
try one 123
```

Make sure your shell supports as many parameters to sed as you have in your map.

Comment: beautiful one-liner!!

Comment: Pure `sed` & `bash` version:       `sed -f <(sed 's/=> //;s# #/#;s#$#/#;s#^#s/#' file.map) stuff.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly straightforward with Tcl:

```tcl
set fA [open listA r]
set fB [open listB r]
set fin [open input.file r]
set fout [open output.file w]

# read listA and listB and create the mapping of corresponding lines
while {[gets $fA strA] != -1} {
    set strB [gets $fB]
    lappend map $strA $strB
}

# apply the mapping to the input file
puts $fout [string map $map [read $fin]]

# if the file is large, do it line by line instead
#while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
#    puts $fout [string map $map $line]
#}

close $fA
close $fB
close $fin
close $fout

file rename output.file input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in `bash`. Get your lists into arrays.

```
listA=(a b c)
listB=(d e f)
data=$(<file)
echo "${data//${listA[2]}/${listB[2]}}" #change the 3rd element. Redirect to file where necessary
```