# Substituting words with sed awk or grep

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to replace certain words in text files. Specifically English spelling of words with the American spelling. I have two arrays of the spellings which are ordered the same i.e.

list_1=['cosy', 'carat', 'cheque']
list_2=['cozy', 'karat', 'check']

Am I able to search a text file for elements in list_1 and substitute with respect to the elements in list_2?

Comment: Yes, use awk. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, by Arnold Robbins if you don't already have it and let us know if you have any questions after you've tried to write a script to do it.

Comment: "Am I able...?" I dunno. Are you able? I'm pretty sure it's possible, though.

Comment: Look at this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198098/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-replace-list-of-strings-with-another-list-in-unix-fi)

Answer (score 2):

This approach assumes that you have access to GNU `sed`.

The first thing to do is get the information out of those lists using this script:

```
$ cat script.sh
list_1=('cosy' 'carat' 'cheque')
list_2=('cozy' 'karat' 'check')
for i in "${!list_1[@]}"
do
    echo "s/\\b${list_1[i]}\\b/${list_2[i]}/g"
done >spelling.sed
```

This produces the file:

```
$ cat spelling.sed 
s/\bcosy\b/cozy/g
s/\bcarat\b/karat/g
s/\bcheque\b/check/g
```

Now, we can use that file to change spellings.  For example:

```
$ echo "Decosy makes a cosy cheque." | sed -f spelling.sed
Decosy makes a cozy check.
```

Note that the spelling of `Decosy` is not changed.  This is because of the use of the GNU extension `\b` which denotes word boundaries.  In this way, only whole words are changed.

Comment: this solution works, but it full scan the input file for each word in the list.
Hope there is `sed` script that can do it in one scan.

Comment: @DudiBoy No, please look again.  The input is actually processed in _one scan_ using `sed -f spelling.sed`.  The loop that you see is only for creating `spelling.sed` .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` script that do the task in one file scan.

`script.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    patsplit(list1, arr1, /[[:alpha:]]+/);  # read array of word from list1
    patsplit(list2, arr2, /[[:alpha:]]+/);  # read array of word from list2
}
{                                    
    for (i in arr1) gsub(arr1[i], arr2[i]); # for each line, replace all words in arrays
}
1
```

execution:

```
 list_1=['cosy', 'carat', 'cheque']
 list_2=['cozy', 'karat', 'check'] 
 awk -v list1=$list_1 -v list2=$list_2 -f script.awk input.txt
```

Note this solution is not considering capitalized words.