# How to iterate word by word in array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, if-statement, grep

i have a simple script, where i make search of words from file

```
words="you are hogan"

for i in $words; do
if grep -q "$i" text.txt; then
        echo "word(s) are exists"
        grep "$i" text.txt
else
        echo "word(s) are not exists"
fi
done
```

it works, i can make grep word by word. My script is is the same:

```
grep "you" text.txt
grep "are" text.txt
grep "hogan" text.txt
```

but, the i received another task. i want to search and replace word by word text.
so, i should create second variable, with words, what i should use instead words from first variable `$words`. how i understand, that i should in one loop use two variables. i know, that i can use array in this case.
ok, let's do it, i tries to make grep, like first example:

```
words="you are hogan"
words2="wwe wwf nukem"

for ((i=0;i<${#words[@]};++i)); do
if grep -q "${words[i]}" text.txt; then
        echo "word(s) are exists"
        echo "${words[i]}"
else
        echo "word(s) are not exists"
fi
done
```

result is not good.

```
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i<1 ))
+ grep -q 'you are hogan' text.txt
+ echo 'word(s) are not exists'
word(s) are not exists
```

How you can see, it tries to make grep of all phraza, not for each word. how can i do grep command for each word, like first example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to replace list of strings with another list in Unix file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198098/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-replace-list-of-strings-with-another-list-in-unix-fi)

Answer (score 2):

Your second syntax you're trying to treat `words` like it's an array, but it's a string.  If you wanted it to be an array you could initialize it differently:

```
words=("you" "are" "hogan")
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    if grep -q "$word" text.txt; then
        printf 'Word exists: %s\n' "$word"
    else
        printf 'Word not found: %s\n' "$word"
    fi
done
```

or use your approach if you want the indexes so you can access the same index in the other field.

Comment: it is the same, that i use in first example. i need use two variable in loop.`words` and `words2`

Comment: It's the same output, but it's crucially different in that it uses an array instead of a string with word splitting, that's the key that you need here

Comment: @Piduna also, you haven't shown what you want to do with the second array, if you want to replace things `sed` would be a better choice than `grep`